# Making Qwidget Transparent on VideoWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a QWidget which should take place over the central widget of my application which is a VideoWidget for playing video. The problem is that I can't set background of the QWidget to be transparent.

Comment: Please provided the code you have already tried / where you a stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Use a StyleSheet (you can do that in code with setStylesheet or in the ui file : RMB on the widget you want "Change stylesheet" or even in the properties tab)

for instance

```
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 50);"
```

gives a yellow transparant look:(example of a button used on top of another button)
[image: example of a button used on top of another button]

With stylesheets you can control the look of a complete program or just the specific widgets you want. More info in the [style sheet reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the full Widget invisible:

```
QWidget::setHidden(true);
```